# Understand super() in diamond inheritance

Tags: python, oop, diamond-problem

I am learning python and started learning MRO in inheritance.

I have read the use of super and the way it can be used however I cannot place my understanding for below question. If it was not super I know B is called. D->B->C->A but when super gets added, I don't know why the output is like this

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print("test of A called")
class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print("test of B called")
        super().test()
class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print("test of C called")
        super().test()
class D(B, C):
    def test2(self):
        print("test of D called")
obj=D()
obj.test()
```

Output

```
test of B called
test of C called
test of A called
```

Please help me understand how super is functioning here.

Comment: Not sure if this typo is on purpose: You named the method in the class D `test2()`instead of `test()` so it would be overridden.

Answer (score 9):

`super()` will go to the next class in the method resolution order for which Python follows C3 linerization (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization): Children are called before their parents and multiple parents are called in the order in which they are set.

So if you invoke a method in class D, the MRO is D -> B -> C -> A, but e.g. if you originally invoke it in class B, the MRO is B -> A.

Does that make it clearer?

Edit: so in your example:
You call `D.test()` which does not exist, so it gets delegated to `B.test()` which prints a string and then invokes `super()`. Due to the MRO as described above, B's `super()` in this case is C, so `C.test()` is called next, which then finally invokes `A.test()`.

Comment: so does that mean super also follows MRO method and prints all the test in D->B->C->A? so if I have super, that also will follow the same order? And it would print all the test methods in that order?

Comment: basically, you can think of `super()` as referring to the next class in the MRO. And yes, if you rename `test2()` in D to `test()` and also called super from there, you would get the output from that followed by what you had before.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your inheritance hierarchy:

[image: inheritance diagram]

Most of your classes inherit from just one parent class, except `D` which has two parents. While not explicitly stated, `A` inherits implicitly from `object`.

For an object of any class, follow the diagram backwards toward the root to see the order in which Python will check classes to find the method you've invoked. A `D` instance, for example, will be visited in `D`, `B`, `C`, `A`, `object` order. Here `B` before `C` because it's listed first in the class definition.

It looks like you've been varying your method names slightly (`test2` vs `test`), which is good practice to see how `test` is resolved if it is/is not present in various combinations of superclasses.

`super()` is an explicit request to "invoke the given method from the superclass(es) of the current object."

For further reading, the search terms "Python MRO" should serve you well, leading you to a number of [excellent walkthroughs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/).

Answer (score 0):

This because of `super().test()`. Using super gives ease but  always tricky unnecessary using causes this kind of behavior

Reasons:

- you can see in `D.mro()` `A.test()` comes at last
- but when program goes in `B.test()` from there it directs to `A.test()`
- but mro forces to go `C.test()` before going to `A.test()`
- comment out the `super.test()` in B